# React-Redux: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I seem to have run into an issue when using `dispatch()` with React-Redux. For example, the following action:

```js
export const fetchMetrics = () => {
    dispatch(fetchMetricsBegin);

    APIService.get('/dashboard/info/')
        .then((response) => { 
            dispatch(fetchMetricsSuccess(response));
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => dispatch(fetchMetricsFailure(error)));
};
```

Produces the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'closed' of undefined
> `dispatch`
> `src/internal/observable/pairs.ts:82`

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.8",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried purging `node_module` and `package-lock.json`, but the issue is still occurring. Would welcome any insight. Removing the `dispatch` calls removes the error.

Comment: Should it not be: `dispatch(fetchMetricsBegin());` assuming `fetchMetricsBegin` is an action creator **function**. The error doesn't look to be in the code you posted, usually in the browser content is some information about where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `redux-thunk`. this library will allow you to perform async calls since your function return another function with `dispatch` as param. otherwise thunk will execute the code sync.

```
export const fetchMetrics = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchMetricsBegin);

    APIService.get('/dashboard/info/')
        .then((response) => { 
            dispatch(fetchMetricsSuccess(response));
            return response;
        })
        .catch(error => dispatch(fetchMetricsFailure(error)));
};
```